# Angular 9: Abstract component's children not inheriting its attributes

Tags: angular

I have a module that has components with similar attributes, so I created an abstract `MyFilter<T>` component that has a set of attributes with an `@Injectable` decorater. After upgrading to Angular 9 I'm getting warnings in the console

> Can't bind to 'form' since it isn't a known property of
>   'my-text-filter'.

and errors because the children components are not recognizing the parent's attributes. Here's some code:

```js
@Injectable()
export abstract class MyFilter<T> {

  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  @Input() filterOpened: boolean;
  @Input() enableSubmit: boolean;
  @Output() filterUsed = new EventEmitter<T>();

  abstract useFilter();
}
```

and here's a child component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-text-filter',
  templateUrl: './text-filter.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-filter.scss']
})
export class MyTextFilter extends MyFilter<TextFilter> implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form.get('value').valueChanges.pipe( // ERROR: cannot find 'get' of undefined
        debounceTime(50)
    ).subscribe(() => this.useFilter());
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes) // this doesn't get logged in the console, 
                         // even if I comment out what's in ngOnInit
  }

  useFilter() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `@Directive` decorator to be able to extend it from another component:

```
@Directive()
export abstract class MyFilter<T> {

  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  @Input() filterOpened: boolean;
  @Input() enableSubmit: boolean;
  @Output() filterUsed = new EventEmitter<T>();

  abstract useFilter();
}
```

Comment: Cannot set property ɵfac of class MyFilter {
    constructor() {
        this.filterUsed = new _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__...<omitted>...
} which has only a getter

Comment: I'm getting an error in production. Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: @amouda I'm guessing you are not using the correct path for importing the Output decoraror

Comment: I tried removing the event emitter, now the warning says the whole class MyFilter has only a getter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633963/angular-9-production-error-cannot-set-property-%c9%b5fac-of-abstract-class-myfilte