# Angular 9 production error: Cannot set property ɵfac of (abstract) class MyFilter { } which has only a getter

Tags: angular

I have an abstract component in a library (without ivy) with a `@Directive()` decorator that has some basic attributes and functions to inherit to its children. When I'm trying to use the library in any project, I'm getting the following error in the browser's console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property ɵfac of class MyFilter {} which has only a getter`

Here is the class:

```js
@Directive()
export abstract class MyFilter<T> {

  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  @Input() filterOpened: boolean;
  @Input() enableSubmit: boolean;

  abstract useFilter();
}
```

a child class:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-text-filter',
  templateUrl: './text-filter.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-filter.scss']
})
export class MyTextFilter extends MyFilter<TextFilter> implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  }

  useFilter() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you please define "in production" is that just when you build with `--prod`, does it happen locally or only when deployed etc

Comment: It's a library which I build without ivy and publish to a private npm repository, to use in other projects.

Comment: @amouda did you find a solution for this ? I'm facing the same problem and I can't find a solution for it !

Comment: Not yet, we removed the abstract class for now for time constraints. But try removing the decorator from the abstract class and see if it works.

Comment: @amouda is this issue resolved, if yes can you provide the resolution steps ??

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove the @Directive() decorator from MyFilter class.

Comment: It is the same for services, removing the @Injectable decorator

Comment: Removing the `@Directive()` will also loose the `@Input`. He has put `@Directive` there to have the `@Input`.