# Cannot set property ɵfac after Angular update to latest v13

Tags: angular, ngxs

I updated the project via ng update from **CLI@13.0.0** and **Core@13.2.5** to the latest v13 minor releases **(CLI@13.3.8** / **Core@13.3.11**).

Since the update I got following error in the web console:

```
table.component.ts:231 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property ɵfac of class BaseComponent {
constructor(injector) {
    this.store = injector.get(_ngxs_store__...<omitted>...}
 which has only a getter
at 7857 (table.component.ts:231:2)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
at 32552 (message.service.ts:18:31)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
at 21658 (auth.service.ts:6:21)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
at 197 (dialog.service.ts:31:32)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
at 47819 (route-not-found.component.html:13:5)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
at 98698 (menu-routing.module.ts:86:25)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
at 13785 (menu.module.ts:12:68)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
at 60796 (app.component.ts:30:26)
```

The component itself is an abstract BaseComponent used to be extended, the DI is managed by passing the Injector to the super constructor.

I already researched and came across [Angular 9 production error: Cannot set property ɵfac of (abstract) class MyFilter { } which has only a getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633963/angular-9-production-error-cannot-set-property-%C9%B5fac-of-abstract-class-myfilte)

Removing the **@Component** Tag removes the error but why shouldn't it work anymore? Furthermore after removing the tag another error appears in the console (I'm using **NGXS@3.7.3** and note that the NGX-Store worked before, no code change in between)

```
core.mjs:6494 ERROR Error: You have forgotten to import the NGXS module!
at throwSelectFactoryNotConnectedError (ngxs-store.js:73:1) [angular]
at createSelectObservableIvy (ngxs-store.js:3844:1) [angular]
at createSelectObservable (ngxs-store.js:3800:1) [angular]
at dev/vendor.js:86124:36 [angular]
at doInnerSub (mergeInternals.js:19:18) [angular]
at outerNext (mergeInternals.js:14:1) [angular]
at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:1) [angular]
at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:1) [angular]
at ReplaySubject._subscribe (ReplaySubject.js:31:1) [angular]
at ReplaySubject._trySubscribe (Observable.js:37:1) [angular]
at ReplaySubject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:74:1) [angular]
at dev/vendor.js:98953:30 [angular]
at errorContext (errorContext.js:19:1) [angular]
at ReplaySubject.subscribe (Observable.js:22:21) [angular]
```

Anyone got an idea? I'm stuck on this. Thank you!

Comment: This is a known issue which is tracked here: https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/1854. You've done the right thing that you've replaced `@Select` with `store.select`. The `@Select` decorator is deprecated and will be removed in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

the @Select Tags from the ngxs/store seem to be conflicting. When replacing them with select functions from the store the BaseComponents work fine!